Does JavaScript's Array.prototype.fill() always create a packed array?
According to this discussion, once a JavaScript array becomes sparse at any point over the course of its lifetime, it forever remains holey. But if I were a V8 developer, I would probably optimize Array.prototype.fill() to always upgrade the underlying data structure to packed when called on its entirety e.g. Array(10).fill() because there's no reason why it can't and it doesn't add much overhead. (I know that setters and prototypal inheritance need to be taken into consideration but that's also the case with Array.prototype.push() which works on packed arrays.)
So my question is: does V8 in fact optimize holey arrays to become packed arrays in this one case where Array.prototype.fill() has been called on the entire length of the array? It's so easy to just create a new underlying packed array for its data structure before filling it with values. And if not then why not?

If you're curious what a specific (open source) javascript engine does, why not read the source.

@Evert I definitely tried

@Evert you could write that comment under pretty much every question on StackOverflow - "Just read the specification" - I must say I could not answer this question even though I have read parts of the V8 codebase - also I find it interesting as it highlights what is ultimately a gap in the JS array constructor - If there was a constructor for length + element the array could easily be created in a packed state.

@JonasWilms for questions where someone wants to know how a specific implementation is written, it's always worth stating in the question that going to the source has been attempted. "What research has been done" is a valid question I think. Even if this wasn't the case for this question, people tend to forget a lot of information is just out there. "What have you tried to solve your problem" is a good thing to include in any question.

(V8 developer here.)
The current state of things is that A.p.fill() never changes the holeyness/packedness of the array it operates on.
Note that being "holey" is very different from being "sparse" (aka "in dictionary mode"). Holey arrays still have what you probably mean when you say "underlying packed array for its data structure" (I'd call it an "array-like backing store", as opposed to a "dictionary backing store").
A.p.fill technically could mark arrays as packed, and perhaps it should, that's certainly been discussed. Reasons for the current behavior include:

Flip-flopping the same array between different states repeatedly can easily have negative (and non-local) effects, it's generally better to let internal representations and other choices stabilize to whatever the current application needs them to be.
The difference between holey and packed arrays is so small that it very often just doesn't matter at all.

So, in summary: don't worry about it.

Thanks. Maybe a good compromise would be to switch to packed only in the case where Array.prototype.fill() is used to immediately initialize a newly instantiated array and before any other operations have been performed. E.g. Array(1000).fill(0); Because as of yet there's no way to initialize a packed array of a predefined size without using weird tricks like calling Array.apply() that just add to the overhead of instantiating the array. But that's just my two cents seeing that Array.prototype.fill() is a very common way to initialize an array.

So basically holey, double + smi are basically just tags to skip != the_hole, IsDouble(...) + IsSmi(...) when accessing the array values? And I agree to the previous comment that it is quite strange that JavaScript has no way to create a filled array of certain size - I guess it is quite a common scenario which is currently holey but does not have to be.

@JonasWilms Smi arrays and packed arrays just avoid checks when loading elements, yes. Double arrays store unboxed doubles, so that's a bigger difference. Regarding being unable to create packed arrays of a given size: "don't worry about it" still applies.

@jmrk Mathias mentioned that it's better to not worry and allocate arrays at a predefined size if you know it in advance in his elements kinds talk. But not before emphasizing how much more efficient it is to avoid holey arrays if you can help it. So why not allow this one optimization where you can initialize a packed array at a predefined size? Seems reasonable.

@PHPGuru Why are you worrying about it?

@PHPGuru From the Elements kinds in V8 blog post you just linked: "For real-world coding patterns, the performance difference between accessing holey or packed arrays is usually too small to matter or even be measurable.".

Thanks. Yeah I definitely fall into the not-worried camp. I'll even always choose Array.prototype.slice() over Array.from() when operating on array-likes even though only the latter returns a packed array. I have just seen some conflicting information out there and wanted to get some clarity especially since I saw room for an optimization. And Mathias had mentioned adding optimizations like that to future versions. And it would definitely make sense that newly instantiated arrays initialized with Array.prototype.fill() would be best represented with a packed underlying array. bc why not?

@PHPGuru well, how do you know it is "newly instantiated"? Consider const arr = new Array(100); while(true) { arr.fill(0); /* ... */ delete arr[0]; /* ... */ }

@JonasWilms What I'm saying is that JavaScript engines should mark a newly instantiated empty array as neither packed nor holey, but in an uninitialized state. Then as soon as an operation is performed on it, it would choose which state to take: packed if optimizable operations such as Array.prototype.fill() are performed on it, and holey for anything else. In your example it should only become packed for the first call on fill(). After that when the delete is performed, it would be downgraded to holey and there's no need for further fill() operations to upgrade it back to packed again.
